Почему не подцепляются стили?
Есть потребность в установке ui кита  - при установке компонента (они каждый в своей либе и  явного импорта стилей не требуют) и его последующем импорте - не навешиваются стили, если ручками задать глобально - то работает,  они наиписаны на scss - подскажите, куда копать?
используется вепбак
{
  test: /\.scss/,
  include: [/node_modules\/@company\/component/],
  use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader'],
}

